Using one momentary switch for multiple IC's at different pull-up voltage levels
I am modifying a car stereo to add bluetooth support, as part of this I would like to piggy-back onto the existing front panel momentary switches to control the bluetooth module (play/pause, next, previous).
The bluetooth board uses a CSR8645 IC, which from my measurements seems to supply ~1.5v via pin 1 to the switch input pins (2,3,4) when depressed, but I cannot find a datasheet for the exact module I am using.
The radio, however uses a NEC UPD75518 which seems to send a 5.6v signal to the switch input pins and when held begins to pulse as a square wave (presumably so that when held the switch behaves differently, eg to keep decreasing the balance to the left when held). How can I wire up the radios momentary switches to the bluetooth module without causing issues? I do not need the radio to not see the switch press (although this would be nice), as the functions of the buttons I choose won't do anything. I have attached a shchematic of how the switches on the radio are connected - it seems inputs KI-X are connected to inputs K0-X when the switch is depressed. All of these pins are connected to what I think is the 5.6v rail from Pin 80 via resistors, I am not sure how this setup works.




the simplest solution may be to insert a control circuit between the keypad and P101 ... or between P101 and the rest of the stereo

Can you mount flat tactile switches like PTS540JK035SMTRLFS between the mechanical buttons and the existing keyboard matrix PCB?

That's an interesting idea, I'll look Into it thank you. Given I need to switch other inputs a multiplexer would be the cleaner option.

I strongly suggest that you consider adding full isolation circuitry in the form of A / B selection analogue mux switches so that the particular switches that you want to assign dual mode functionality to can operate properly in the NEC UPD75518 mode or in the CSR8645 IC mode. It is clear from the schematic that trying to do this without the A/B mode selection will really upset the operational mode of one component or the other if you try to implement this without full isolation.
Implementing this with the suggested isolation does lead to a decision that has to be made regarding how to select the A or B mode on the analogue switch circuits that you would add. There may be some state signal somewhere in the equipment that you can use for this purpose but that is really beyond the scope of this answer. In the worst case you may need to add one additional button to be used for this purpose OR decommission one button function in the NEC UPD75518 mode to be fully reassigned to this mode selection.
In the end it may very well turn out that all this is a lot more bother than simply trying to find a way to add a new set of buttons for the bluetooth chip functions.
